# Getting ***stack smashing detected*** while counting array length

Tags: c, gcc

I am using VS code on Ubuntu 20.04. I am learning C programming. The program is to count length of array using function. while running the program I can give input to the array but not getting the length of array.The code is :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int length(char input[])
{
    int count=0;
    for(int i=0;input[i]!=0;i++)
    {
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
int main()
{
    char name[10];
    printf("Enter name:");
    scanf("%s",&name[10]);
    int count=length(name);
    printf("%d",count);

}
```

Output:

```
Enter name:abc
*** stack smashing detected; terminated
Aborted (core dumped)
```

What is wrong with the code?

Comment: `scanf("%s",&name[10]);` -> `scanf("%s",&name[0]);` or `scanf("%s",name);`, currently you ask `scanf` to write *after* you array, which has undefined behavior. To also limit read length is better `scanf("%9s",name);`, and to check you read mush better `if (scanf("%9s",name) != 1) ...error..; else { ... }`

Comment: `&name[10]` is a pointer to 10th non-existing element of `name`.

Comment: @Ruks there is no reason to do while checking `scanf` returns 1

Comment: @bruno Problem is soved. Also while using only name i was getting error ```char (*) [10]```

Comment: @TrusharGavit I put an answer if you are interresting, with more than your initial problem. you have `error char (*) [10]` if you use `&name`

Comment: why don't you use `strlen(name)` or `while(*input++) {++count;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Enter name:abc
>   *** stack smashing detected; terminated
>   Aborted (core dumped)

this is because in

> ```
> scanf("%s",&name[10]);
> ```

you ask `scanf` to write *after* the array with an undefined behavior

you wanted

```
scanf("%s",&name[0]);
```

or more simple

```
scanf("%s",name);
```

But if the input has more than 9 characters you have an other undefined behavior writing again after the array, so better to limit the number of written characters doing :

```
scanf("%9s",name);
```

I use 9 to let the place of the null character ending the string

Anyway this is not yet perfect because you do not detect nothing is read, for instance because you redirect the input on an empty file, so :

```
if (scanf("%9s",name) == 1) {
  ...
}
```

but may be you also wanted to read spaces among the other characters, to read *john doe* for instance, in that case :

```
if (scanf(" %9[^\n]",name) == 1) {
  ...
}
```

note the space before the '%' allowing to bypass spaces at the beginning of the answer (but not at the end), if you want to get them remove that space

---

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int length(char input[])
{
    int count=0;
    for(int i=0;input[i]!=0;i++)
    {
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
int main()
{
    char name[10];
    printf("Enter name:");
    if (scanf(" %9[^\n]", name) == 1) {
      int count=length(name);
      printf("%d\n",count);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation and executions :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -Wall c.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Enter name:abc
3
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Enter name:jonh doe
8
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Enter name:to long but cut
9
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Note also in your function `length` the variables *i* and *count* always have the same value, so only one is enough

Answer (score 0):

```
char name[10];
printf("Enter name:");
scanf("%s",&name[10]);
```

With `&name[10]` you attempt to access a non-existing 10th element of array `name` and want to write the string from this element on. Array Index counting starts at `0`, not `1`. The `10` at the definition of `name` is only to indicate 10 elements.

The element pointed to will be the element where the first character of the string is stored. All subsequent characters go into subsequent elements of `name`.

You need to use:

```
scanf("%s",&name[0]);
```

or

```
scanf("%s",name);
```

as `name` decays to a pointer to its first element.

---

But rather use `fgets()`:

```
fgets(name, sizeof(name), stdin);
```

which ensures that you wan´t write beyond the bounds of the pointed `char` array.

Comment: `fgets` saves the newline if it is enter and the input line is not too long, this is not the case with OP `scanf("%s"`, may be warm about that ?